# timer555 single pulse

Tags: capacitor

I'm having a quiz show project with LEDs, and a buzzer. One LED must be lit up and the buzzer should work for about 0.5 sec.
I am stuck on the problem that using circuit output state (which gets high and remains high till reset comes), I will set the trigger pin of timer555 low, but since it's continuously low, the buzzer, which is connected to the output of timer555, buzzes repeatedly.
 I'm wondering what I could do to convert a constant output to a fixed 0.5 pulse using a timer555.

Comment: Single pulse = monostable.

Comment: I know how to make use of monostable mode generally, but with my problem the trigger part is constant low (thus not a pulse), and that makes it buzz repeatedly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn the input from a level to a edge trigger:

[image]

by adding a capacitor as shown to create a differentiator.  Try using 0.1 µF to start.  The pullup resistor, Rd can be 10K or so.  The diode is a 1N4148.

The 555 will not re-trigger until after the input has been restored to Vcc and then goes low again, no matter how long the original pulse is.